# Cant generate folders contains Offline Database after Android APK installation

Tags: android, database, sqlite, offline

I use SQLite as my offline database. After the APK installation, I couldn't find the folders that I made. I want to put the database in device Storage : /storage/emulated/0 (Samsung device where I tested my program).

I already put this in my manifest :

```
<manifest android:installLocation="preferExternal" />
```

To install APK, i copied it directly from **bin** to my phone external storage. Did I miss something?

**notes: I need for users to be able to access files (.TXT and .XML) from device storage, so the folders and files inside shouldn't be hidden.

I'd appreciate your kind reply.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`installLocation="preferExternal"` refers to the app installation, not to an eventual **database** (which I don't see mentioned anywhere in your question, other than in its title).

`i copied it directly from bin to my phone external storage. Did I miss something?` **YES**: this is not enough.
You have to **install** the apk, after copying it - you'll need a file manager to launch it.
OR (better) **activate your Debug Options** and run the app from the IDE directly onto your phone (you'll need to install the ADB Bridge, aka **USB driver**, aka ADB Composite Interface).

`so the folders and files inside shouldn't be hidden.` Every file in the apk is **private** to your app.
Other than this, your SD Card and then use them from there.
Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get the path to your SD Card.

If you need some clarification on **databases**, please post a specific question about that matter.

Comment: Ok, I'll clarify my question in more detail way. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Well, maybe in general concept. For more the detail way, I'll post new question. Thx